# Send custom metrics from compute engine to google cloud monitoring

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-compute-engine

I have written a shell script for backing up data from blob store after regular intervals in a VM instance( Google compute engine ). Now that, I want to monitor it using google cloud monitoring ( https://app.google.stackdriver.com ). In case of any failure of script, I would like to get a SMS/E-mail. Is there any way that I can push a custom metric to cloud monitoring from a script in compute engine to achieve this?

PS : I have already implemented sendGrid for sending emails to myself, in case of failure. But I would like to use Google cloud monitoring for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what would be definition of the failure of script.

As an example, if you want to monitor the script to know if it is running and not stopped, you can create a [custom metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/) that its value is being populated by your script.
Set up an alerting policy in [Google Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs) with `Metric Absence` as condition for your custom metric and add a notification method. Then, you should be notified if the script stopped working.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on it, Kamran. Should I use Lightweight or labelled metric?

Comment: For my example, a lightweight custom metric should do the job.